# How to create a ratio using Temp variables and Temp Tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a ratio to determine a decline rate.

I have created two temp tables and Stored the correct information inside them. What I need now Is a ratio created from the two temp tables

I need to create a ratio from the two temp tables and store it inside the `@DECLINERATE` variable. Then use this ratio to `order by`

I have tried to do the calculation within the `select` part of the statement for the two temp tables, Which I believe is possible I just cant seem to get it working

Here  is the part i'm struggling with:

```
DECLARE @DECLINERATE INT;
SET @DECLINERATE =  (SELECT (t2.[Number Of Individual Sales] / t1.[Number Of Individual Sales] * 100) as [Decline RATIO]
    FROM #TempTbl12MonthDecline1 t1 
    join #TempTbl12MonthDecline2 t2 on 
    t1.[Number Of Individual Sales] = t2.[Number Of Individual Sales] )
```

I'm expecting to get a ratio that is created from `[AMOUNT OF INDIVIDUAL SALES]`  of both the temp tables. However, I am currently receiving error when executing code posted:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error indicate and since you declare variable as scalar you must assign single value at once wherein your table got multiple values with result of expression:

```
(t2.[Number Of Individual Sales] / t1.[Number Of Individual Sales] * 100)
```

However, Any difficulties using your expression directly in `order by` clause as follows:

```
SELECT  (t2.[Number Of Individual Sales] / t1.[Number Of Individual Sales] * 100) as [Decline RATIO]
FROM    #TempTbl12MonthDecline1 t1 
        join 
        #TempTbl12MonthDecline2 t2 
        on t1.[Number Of Individual Sales] = t2.[Number Of Individual Sales] 
Order by [Decline RATIO] DESC
```

Comment: Thank you Shekar. This was not a complete fix to what I wanted but did get me heading in the right direction. Have a great day man!